# Compare sublists in a list

Tags: compare

I want to compare sublist I get from a list, if the numbers of the sublist are the same return True, like this:

> > > list([[2,1,1,6],[6,2,1],[2,2,6,1],[2,1,6]])
> > >       True

but if it haven't the same numbers in the sublist return False

> > > list([[2,1,1,6],[2,8,6,1],[2,1,6]])
> > >       False

Comment: To clarify, you're asking whether "if the numbers of *any one* sublist are equal to *any one of the other sublist* in the list, return true, otherwise return false" correct?

Comment: All the numbers of each sublist have to be same to return true and doesn't matter if they are repeated